# No available formula or cask with the name "md5sha1sum#!/bin/bash"

Tags: homebrew

I keep getting this weird brew warning, logs are below:

```
Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "md5sha1sum#!/bin/bash".
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap md5sha1sum#!/bin
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
ERROR:  Unexpected mod_checksum '==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
```

What should I do?
I tried brew tap md5sha1sum#!/bin, not working.

Comment: `md5sha1sum` is a valid formula name, but `#!/bin/bash` looks like a shebang (first line of a shell script, nothing at all to do with formula names). I'd guess a shells script somehow got appended to a config/settings/whatever file, but I have no idea which file and how it might have happened. Exactly when do you get this error? Also, Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage or troubleshooting; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask about things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gordon said, `md5sha1sum` is [the formula name](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/md5sha1sum), but `#!/bin/bash` is [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

It can be confirmed by either the CLI search, or [formulae search page](https://formulae.brew.sh/).

```
$ brew search md5sha1sum
==> Formulae
md5sha1sum
```

[image]